# Legend changes the chart order

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a line chart using nvd3 as follows :

[image]

The issue happens when the legend is used to interact with chart. Since it uses the order of rendering to position each series, it can change the way information is displayed completely.  For example, if i click on `Blocked` (disabling the other) then `Requests` (enabling it back). The result is as follows:

[image]

Which is not very nice.
Looking at the documentation and code I could not find many options on how to handle this issue.

Comment: For now my solution is to re-render the whole chart when both series are active. Buts is not a good solution. And also I lose the nice looking animation of the series coming back to the chart.

Comment: If you could put your code on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), its easier to have a look at the code and point you in the correct direction.